# Is there an incompatibility in LineNumberReader in Java 17?

Tags: java, io

suggest the snippet below: Basically, it reads the string One\nTwo completely, piping it through a LineNumberReader. So far, nothing special. Problem: On Java 8, and Java 11, the output is 1. On Java 17, however, the output is 2. (Looks, like the last, unterminated line is counted in the latter case, but isn't in the former cases.

Question: Is this a known incompatibility? Is it documented, and intentional?

Thanks,

Jochen

```
    final StringReader sr = new StringReader("One\nTwo");
    final LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(sr);
    for (;;) {
        final int c = lnr.read();
        if (c == -1) {
            System.out.println("Line number=" + lnr.getLineNumber());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Partial answer: The behaviour is documented. Quoting the Javadocs from Java 17:

This number increments at every line terminator as the data is read, _and at the end of the stream_ if the last character in the stream is not a line terminator.

Comment: Why did you comment exactly what my answer already says after I posted?  Can you explain why you think its a partial answer? (You literally say "Is it documented" in the question...)

Answer (score 5):

Looks intentional to me as the Java 17 docs for `read` show the difference:

[Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html#read--)

> Read a single character. Line terminators are compressed into single newline ('\n') characters. Whenever a line terminator is read the current line number is incremented.

[Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/LineNumberReader.html?is-external=true#read())

> Read a single character. Line terminators are compressed into single newline ('\n') characters. Whenever a line terminator is read the current line number is incremented.

[Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/LineNumberReader.html#read())

> Read a single character. Line terminators are compressed into single
> newline ('\n') characters. The current line number is incremented
> whenever a line terminator is read, **or when the end of the stream is
> reached and the last character in the stream is not a line terminator.**